# Escribir fichero XML en servidor via JS

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, xml

Tengo una página HTML en local,con una de sus páginas que contiene formulario que tiene que modificar un archivo XML que forma parte del proyecto. El fichero forma parte de la página, no de la máquina que fuera cliente. El XML debe quedar grabado como fichero, no como muestra de como queda.

Formulario HTML:

```
<form>    
            Titulo: <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo"><br />
            Descripcion: <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"><br />
            Agregar imagen: <select id="seleccion">
                <option onclick='hide()' value="A" selected="selected">No</option>
                <option onclick='unhide()' value="b">S&iacute;</option>
            </select>
            <input type="file" class='hidden' id='imag' accept="image/*"/><br />
            <button type="reset" onclick='hide()'>Reiniciar campos</button> <button type="button" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>
        </form>
```

En enviar, tengo el siguiente código en JS

```
function enviar()
{
    var titulo=document.getElementById("titulo").value;
    var desc=document.getElementById("desc").value;
    var e=document.getElementById("seleccion");
    var img;
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value=="b")
        img=recuperar_nombre(); //No va
    else
        img="a";

    if (titulo==null||titulo=="")
        alert("Rellene el título")
    else
        if (desc==null|| desc=="")
            alert("Rellene la descripción")
        else
            if (img=="")
                alert("Desmarque la subida de archivos")
            else
                grabar_xml(titulo,desc,img); //Esto es en lo que pido ayuda. Sería abrir el fichero para escritura, saltarse el elemento raíz, escribir, guardar, y salir, sin mostrar
}
```

El XML, por si hiciera falta:

```
<articulos>
<articulo>
    <article>
        <h2>TEST</h2>
        <p></p>
    </article>
    <img href=''></img>
</articulo>
<articulo>
    <article>
        <h2>prueba</h2>
        <p></p>
    </article>
    <img href=''></img>
</articulo>
```

Comment: Aquí tienes una buena respuesta (en inglés). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117402/xml-creating-editing-and-saving-in-js#answer-28118547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer cambios en el lado del `servidor`, primeramente deberías tener un `servidor` encargado de leer y escribir en ese fichero `xml`. El código que muestras asumo que es el código que se ejecuta en el `cliente` y este, a su vez, no tiene acceso a ese fichero, porque como bien dices, no está en la máquina del `cliente`.

En este caso deberías montar un `servidor` con `php` por ejemplo y crear un fichero que reciba los parametros enviados desde tu código `JavaScript` (titulo, descripción, etc) y que los guarde en el fichero `xml`. Para ello, desde tu formulario debes de definir el tipo de petición que harás al servidor `action="/tufichero.php"` y un `method="POST"` por ejemplo.

En `tufichero.php` deberías tener algo como:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["titulo"]) && isset($_POST["descripcion"]) .....){
        //escribir en el fichero los parametros de $_POST
    }
```

Y si lo que quieres es simplemente escribir en un fichero `xml` desde `JavaScript` puedes mirar un ejemplo sencillo [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_create.asp).

Para hacer una lectura de un fichero `xml` a través de una petición `ajax`:

```
   var boton = document.getElementById("tuidboton");
        boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                peticion_http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                peticion_http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            peticion_http.onreadystatechange = mostrarContenido;
            peticion_http.open('POST', '/tufichero.xml', true);
            peticion_http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            peticion_http.send(null);

            function mostrarContenido() {

                if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) {
                    if(peticion_http.status == 200) { //cuando la petición haya resultado exitosa

                        var documento = peticion_http.responseXML;
                        //este es el dom del documento.. recorre y muestra lo que desees
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Me lo temia...
[Salto de linea, ya que no hay forma de ponerlo en el comentario]
Otra de las funciones, via ajax, accede al fichero XML y lo muestra, pero eso es acceso de lectura, en esencia...
[Salto de linea, ya que no hay forma de ponerlo en el comentario]
Es parte del requisito técnico que me piden usar solamente lenguajes de marcas, CSS y JS, sin php, java, etc... ni servidores que le hagan respaldo (usar el navegador como servidor local)

Comment: Por cierto, el salto de línea lo puedes hacer con ´shift´+ ´intro´ :)

Comment: Shift+intro 4 veces da un mensaje seguido, en la visualización.
No es otra subpregunta, ya que la visualización está hecha... sino que creo que esto es una prueba trampa o algo...

Comment: Entiendo, entonces solamente necesitas acceder e insertar nodos en un fichero xml desde js verdad?

Comment: En principio, sí, el formulario recibe la información, la procesa la función enviar y grabar_xml debería acceder y agregar el nodo al fichero, guardando el fichero detrás, pero como bien has dicho, el JS lo ejecuta el cliente, aunque el navegador sea el servidor.